# Creating a Table of Function Outputs

Tags: r

I have a function in R that returns a number as the last line of code.

Is there a way of repeating the function X amount of times and creating a table representing how many times the number comes up?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replicate` to execute the function 'n' times, then `unlist` the `list` output (as `simplify = FALSE`) and get the frequency with `table`

```
n <- 10
table(unlist(replicate(n, yourfun, simplify = FALSE)))
```

Comment: I knew it would be something easy! Thank you so much. Does this create a table of results too?

Comment: Of course, you've been great. I don't suppose you know how to make these into a table so I can see over say 50 replications how many times a given number is produced?

Comment: It's representing a player number. So can be any positive integer

Comment: Try `table(unlist(replicate(n, yourfun, simplify = FALSE)))`

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I needed. You're a hero!

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `sapply`

```
table(c(sapply(seq(n),yourfun)))
```